# Including extra directories with Keter

Tags: haskell, yesod, keter

I have a Yesod site and have created a handler for handling downloads and enforcing constraints.  My Yesod project directory has a subdirectory called `downloads`, and it contains files I want the user to be able to download if they are logged in.  The handler works great in my development and staging boxes, but breaks when I transfer to production.  I tracked the problem down to `yesod keter` not archiving the files when it builds its bundle.

How do I convince `keter` to include the directory?

Comment: I forget the exact details, but I think that `yesod keter`'s functionality is covered by another package. Maybe that has more configuration options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the `yesod keter` command does is create a `.tar.gz` compressed archive file with the `.keter` extension containing the following subdirectories:

- `config`: an exact copy of the identically named directory in your source tree
- `dist`: contains a subdirectory `bin` containing your app's binary
- `static`: an exact copy of the identically named directory in your source tree

Note that the path to your app's binary is set in `config/keter.yml` via the `exec` setting while the path to your static files is set via the `root` setting. The exact set of files included by the `yesod keter` command is specified in the [`findFiles`](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/master/yesod-bin/Keter.hs#L58) function if you want to take a look at the source code.

If you want to customize the contents of your `.keter` file it is probably most straightforward to write a shell script to create the archive. With this script you can add arbitrary extra directories to the archive.

The bare minimum bash script you'd need to emulate the behaviour of `yesod keter` is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
tar cvf myapp.keter config/ dist/bin/ static/
```

You can customize this however you want to produce the correct content. Adding `download/` to the end of this command line should do the trick.